# AD Server integration for User Authentication in WiJungle

Tags: networking, firewall, active-directory, authentication

I have 100 windows PC's in our organization and all are connected to Active Directory Server. We have two working shifts, is it possible that as and when people from different shifts login in to the same PC, they get the internet access and respective firewall policies are applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, feature is called WiJungle Authentication Suite.

Steps:

1. Go to User Management->Authentication Server->Add Server
2. Select AD and add all respective fields.
3. Import AD Wizard->select user groups->import
4. Open AD Server
5. Install WAS Service and App
6. Fill Admin username and password